# unity3d c# typing to file fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I want to save what I type to a text file. The code bellow works but when I type too fast, the file has no time to include all the character typed.
Would anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

```
using System.IO; 

string inp;

void Update () 
{
    if
    (
        Input.anyKeyDown
    )
    {

        inp=inp+(string)Input.inputString;

        string path="txt/txttst001.txt";

            File.WriteAllText
            (
                path, 
                inp
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: The write to file is synchronous so there's no possibility to lose data because of writing, it's more factible the Update function isn't being called fast enough, if Update is tied to VSync then it will update 60 times per second, so it will not catch fast key presses.

Comment: Use OnGUI() : http://www.sophiehoulden.com/super-fast-input-in-unity/ ?

Comment: great article! thx

Answer (score 0):

Try using a StreamWriter instead:

```
using System.IO; 

string inp;

void Update () 

{
    if
    (
        Input.anyKeyDown
    )
    {

    inp=inp+(string)Input.inputString;

    string path="txt/txttst001.txt";

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path,true)){
        file.Write(inp);
    }
}
}
```

For more information on StreamWriter you can check it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried StreamWriter too, same problem happen. The text file is written too slowly, characters in the text file are not updated in real time. I guess I would need some buffer but not sure how to do that. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing a **Fixed Timestep** to lower value in **Time Manager** and using **FixedUpdate** instead of Update.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html